# Prove the following expansion.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Prove that

$${e^{-1} =2(\frac{1}{3!} + \frac{2}{5!} + \frac{3}{7!}  + \frac{4}{9!} ....)}$$.

I am unable to solve it. I know I have to solve it using expansion of ${e^x}$.But I am unable to understand the algebraic manipulation that I have to perform to solve it. Please help me. Thank you! :))

Comment: What are the next terms?

Comment: Giving just 2 terms isn't enough, please add a few more or write a formula.

Comment: I think it may be $\frac{r}{(2r+1)!}$

Comment: Did you miss a + sign?

Comment: I have added few more terms..

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221951/evaluate-sum-k-1-infty-frack2k-1, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/581603/evaluate-frac13-frac14-frac12-frac15-frac13-dots and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/348061/exponential-and-logarithmic-series-find-the-sum-of-22-32-242-3-t

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$$\begin{align}e^{-1}&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n!} \\&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{(-1)^{2n}}{(2n)!}+\frac{(-1)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\right)\\&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(2n+1)-1}{(2n+1)!}\\&=2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n}{(2n+1)!}\\&=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n}{(2n+1)!}\end{align}$$

Comment: Two bottom expressions are identical. Did you mean to have $2$ inside the sum in the pre-last one?

Comment: @Ruslan Not identical. $n=0\to\infty$ in the first, but $n=1\to\infty$ in the second.

Comment: Ah, didn't notice this.